# How to define a ruby array that contains a backslash("\") character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, arrays, backslash

I want to define an array in ruby in following manner

```
A = ["\"]
```

I am stuck here for hours now. Tried several possible combinations of single and double quotes, forward and backward slashes. Alas !!

I have seen this link as well : [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings)
But couldn't understand how to resolve my problem.

Apart from this what I need to do is - 
1. Read a file character by character (which I managed to do !)
2. This file contains a "\" character 
3. I want to do something if my array A includes this backslash

```
A.includes?("\")
```

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some characters which are special and need to be escaped.
Like when you define a string

```
str = " this is test string \
and this contains multiline data \
do you understand the backslash meaning here \
it is being used to denote the continuation of line"
```

In a string defined in a double quotes "", if you need to have a double quote how would you doo that? "\"", this is why when you put a backslash in a string you are telling interpretor you are going to use some special characters and which are escaped by backslash. So when you read a "\" from a file it will be read as "\" this into a ruby string.

```
char = "\\"
char.length # => 1
```

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Yes agree with @naveen

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not with `Array`, your question really involves escape sequences for special characters in strings. As the `\` character is special, you need to first prepend it (escape it) with a leading backslash, like so.

```
"\\"
```

You should also re-read your link and the [section on escape sequences](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences).

Answer (score 1):

You can escape backslash with a backslash in double quotes like:

```
["\\"].include?("\\")
```